# Correl Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I need to apply correl function for each unique ID for A and B 
Is there any way I could do it in excel without repeating for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
First convert columns **A,B,C** into a Table
Second successively filter column **A** by ID
Third copy each set of **B & C** to a different area
Fourth apply =CORREL() to each copy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking whether you can find the correlation for columns A and B for each unique ID. If that is indeed the case, you can find it using the following formula (which assumes that you're listing the IDs in column D, and that the grid you have shown is placed in columns A, B, and C):

```
=CORREL(IF($A$2:$A$11=D2,$B$2:$B11,0),IF($A$2:$A$11=D2,$C$2:$C$11,0))
```

This is an array formula, so you'll need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` instead of just `ENTER`.